# How can I compare whether a data type is, or is not, equal to a specific data type?

Tags: vb.net, validation, types

```
Dim firstName As String

Console.Write("Please enter your first name: ")
firstName = Console.ReadLine() 'Accepts user's first name
```

Now how would I compare the data type of "firstName" to another data type, for example integer? That way, I could use an If statement to compare the data types and output an error message if the data the user inputted is erroneous.

I tried this:

```
Dim firstName As String

Console.Write("Please enter your first name: ")
firstName = Console.ReadLine()

If firstName IsNot GetType(String) Then
    Console.Write("Error, please try again: ")
End If
```

This did not work because every time, the statement would equal false and so the error message would never be outputted regardless of the data type inputted.

Comment: the type of firstname is string, so the test will always get ture, what charcters do you don't want, you could regex these

Comment: You can use [Integer.TryParse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-7.0) to determine if a String can be converted to an Integer. This doesn't really help you determine if a "first name" has been entered or not, though! What if my first name is literally "50"? What if I type in "You can take your first name question and shove it!"; that's a valid string that isn't an integer, but is it a valid "first name"? You need to really define what a "valid first name" is...

Comment: Think about what it is that you're actually asking. Are you saying, without actually saying, that you want to make sure that the text contains nothing but letters? Be precise.

Comment: So how would I go about ensuring that the input is nothing but letters? Would a for loop that compares all characters of the string to a number/special character be the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check the string for letters do something like that:

```
Function CheckForAlphaCharacters(ByVal StringToCheck As String)
    For i = 0 To StringToCheck.Length - 1
        If Not Char.IsLetter(StringToCheck.Chars(i)) Then
            Return False
        End If
    Next

    Return True 'Return true if all elements are characters
End Function
```

You can also check for whitespaces in the string:

```
Function CheckForAlphaCharacters(ByVal StringToCheck As String)
    For i = 0 To StringToCheck.Length - 1
        If Not Char.IsLetter(StringToCheck.Chars(i)) And Not Char.IsWhiteSpace(StringToCheck.Chars(i)) Then
            Return False
        End If
    Next

    Return True 'Return true if all elements are characters or whitespaces
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternate approach using LINQ:

```
Dim firstName As String

Console.Write("Please enter your first name: ")
firstName = Console.ReadLine()

If Not firstName.All(Function(c) Char.IsLetter(c)) Then
    Console.WriteLine("Error, please try again.")
End If
```